# Create directory of dynamically created html files. Flask

Tags: python, flask

I've got a simple flask app, with a templates folder with a bunch of html files that are created by a separate program. I want to (1) serve each of these html files by hitting `localhost:8888/<html_filename>` and
(2) create a directory with hyperlinks to these endpoints on my main `/` endpoint.

Thoughts on how I could get a jinja template to create links to those endpoints? Heres what I've been thinking.

Flask App:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    reports = [f_name for f_name in os.listdir("templates") if f_name.endswith(".html")]
    return render_template("index.html", reports=reports)

@app.route('/<report>')
def render_report(report):
    return render_template(report+'.html')
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Report Directory</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <ul>
        {% for r in reports %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ r }}">{{ r }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head and not tested in any way define a route along the lines of the following:

```
@route("/<string:slug>/", methods=['GET'])
def page(self, slug):

    if slug_exists_as_a_html_file(slug):

        return render_template(slug)

    abort(404)
```

The function (or inline it) )`slug_exists_as_a_html_file` needs to return True if the slug matches a valid html template file, otherwise false.

To generate your report listing use something like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Report Directory</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <ul>
        {% for r in reports %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for('page', slug=r) }}">{{ r }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```